# How to draw css box shadow over element which is directly under it?

Tags: html, css, elementtree

See the following jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Lj56ehwf/

```css
.shadow {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
.container {
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
    Text
</div>
<div class="container">
    This container is drawn <strong>over</strong> the box shadow.
</div>
```

How do you ensure that the box shadow is drawn over the container?
In stead of the container over the shadow.
I think changing the element order is not a good idea.

Comment: I would recommend setting the z-index of the div with the shadow higher than the div below it.

Answer (score 2):

Give `.shadow` a higher `z-index`.

```css
.shadow {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  Text
</div>
<div class="container">
  This container is drawn <strong>over</strong> the box shadow.
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Articles like this one might help understanding this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: So decline and slander my edits and then add them yourself, well played sir.